# date_default_timezone_set(); NOT working

Tags: php, timezone-offset

I have tested this code

```
<?php
//date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Helsinki');
//date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
$date1 = date("Y-m-d");
$unixDate=time();
echo '[{ "DATE" : "'.$date1.'"},{ "UNIXTIME" : "'.$unixDate.'" }]';
?>
```

in several sites (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_php_online.php) including my local server and my hosting server. All of these show the some UNIXTIME in sec even if i change the date_default_timezone_set.

Do you have any idea why that is happening?

Comment: In ferst use `json_encode` function for generate json. In secondary you have this locale on you server?

Comment: You have right i forgot to write header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`time()` is timezone independant. This means, it will always return the time in seconds since january 1 1970, no matter how the timezone is configured. It always takes the UTC-time.

Comment: It is not  timezone independant https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php

Answer (score 1):

> The function time() returns always timestamp that is timezone independent (=UTC).

Source:
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.time.php#100220