# php - date_default_timezone_set not working, Why?

Tags: php, timezone

date_default_timezone_set not working.

my code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>";
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Shanghai");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>";
ini_set("date.timezone","UTC");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>";
ini_set("date.timezone","Asia/Shanghai");
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') . "<br>";
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T', time()) . "<br>";
```

all of them return the same date "2017-05-26 12:47:08 CST", why?

---

update:

I have fixed this problem, the reason is that I used the wrong way to change the timezone on CentOS7:

```
cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

this way is right on CentOS6, but in CentOS7 /etc/localtime is linked to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC, so I damaged the UTC timezone.

the right way to change the timezone on CentOS7 is:

```
timedatectl set-timezone "Asia/Shanghai"
```

or

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Shanghai /etc/localtime
```

so I copied /usr/share/zoneinfo/Etc/UTC from other system to my system to fixed this problem.

Answer (score 9):

Try This.

```
<?php
    $now = new DateTime();
    $now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));
    echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T');
?>
```

`time()` is timezone independant. This means, it will always return the time in seconds since january 1 1970, no matter how the timezone is configured. It always takes the UTC-time.'

[date_default_timezone_set(); NOT working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36390778/date-default-timezone-set-not-working)

Also Check this
http://php.net/manual/pl/function.time.php#100220

Comment: please see to code above , I also try "echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s T') ", this not include time(), but it return the same result. and I also try :$now = new DateTime();
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s T'). "<br>"; it return : 2017-05-26 13:14:27 CST, why the timezone is CST(chine)?

Comment: @gdtv But just before you echo that date, you set the timezone to UTC. So echo date( time()) will be the same as your echo as they are both UTC